# Python: Add a list to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to add a list of items to an existing dictionary, but I am not getting the correct number of items. This is my code.

```
d = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 3, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print('Inventory:')
    totnum = 0
    for k,v in d.items():
        print(v, k)
        totnum += v
    print('Total number of items: ' + str(totnum))

displayInventory(d)

print()

dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

def addToInventory(inventory, add):
    new= dict.fromkeys(add, 1)
    for k, v in new.items():
        inventory[k] = v

z = addToInventory(d, dragonLoot)

displayInventory(d)
```

The expected output should be this

```
Inventory:
1 rope
6 torch
5 gold coin
2 dagger
12 arrow
1 ruby
Total number of items: 27
```

Comment: and what output do you get?

Comment: Inventory:
1 rope
6 torch
1 gold coin
1 dagger
12 arrow
1 ruby
Total number of items: 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider restructuring and using a `Counter` like below:

```
from collections import Counter

inventory = Counter({'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 3, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12})


def displayInventory():

    print('Inventory:')

    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(v, k)

    print(f'Total number of items: {sum(inventory.values())}')


displayInventory()

dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
print('--Picked up loot!')

inventory.update(dragonLoot)

displayInventory()
```

Gives:

```
Inventory:
1 rope
6 torch
3 gold coin
1 dagger
12 arrow
Total number of items: 23
--Picked up loot!
Inventory:
1 rope
6 torch
5 gold coin
2 dagger
12 arrow
1 ruby
Total number of items: 27
```

This also means that if you can safely check the inventory for items not already in there like:

```
print(inventory['diamond'])
```

which gives:

```
0
```

(a normal dict would raise a `KeyError`).

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `dict.fromkeys(add, 1)` does something else then you think:

```
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
>>> dict.fromkeys(dragonLoot, 1)
{'gold coin': 1, 'ruby': 1, 'dagger': 1}
```

So it does not count the occurences.

I would change the `addToInventory` function to this:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, add):
    for k in add:
        inventory[k] = inventory.get(k, 0) + 1
```

So you loop over the items you found and add it to your inventory

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects). If you use it, your could would look like this:

```py
d = Counter({'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 3, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12})
loot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
d.update(loot)
print(d)
# Counter('rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 5, 'dagger': 2, 'arrow': 12, 'ruby':1)
```